# How to make item that gets scrolled out of a horizontal scrollview view fade out? [Xamarin forms]

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have hooked up my scrollview to a OnScrolled event. Inside my scrollview i have a stacklayout. The `WidthRequest` of each "row" is 90.

What i tried to do is then begin fading out item when it reaches 45, and increase the index so that it continues fading out the view that is not viewed.

```
    int index = 0;
    private void OnScrolled(object sender, ScrolledEventArgs e)
    {
        for (double i = 0; i < e.ScrollX; i++)
        {
            if (i == 45)
            {
                var itemOne = this._itemsStackLayout.Children[index]; // my horizontal stacklayout inside my scrollview
                itemOne.FadeTo(0, 50, Easing.Linear);
                index++;
            }
        }
    }
```

This is however not working particuraly well, whenever i make a scroll, as far as i can see all the items seems to get faded out and then i am hit with a index out of range exception.

Is there a better way to accomplish this in Xamarin forms to make the item that is getting out of the scrollview fade out instead of moving out from the edge making it more visually pleasing?

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, you used FadeTo method to animate the Opacityproperty of an StackLayout child when Scrollx value is 45.I use you code at my side, if the current ScrollX value is 45, I cannot see anything next.

You said that “as far as i can see all the items seems to get faded out and then i am hit with a index out of range exception”, because Scrollx is more than the childs of stacklayout.